# Call Multiple external jQuery In Front End in Shopify APP

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am creating the shopify public app and did some jquery code in the app in front end. I need to include multiple external jQuery in the front end via app with the help of theme extensions. I have included front_shop.js in schema code which is given below, but i have to include 2 more external js also Please let me know how i can do this

```
    {% schema %}
   {
    "name": "Lyfsize",
    "target": "section",
    "stylesheet": "front_shop.css",
    "javascript": "front_shop.js",
    "templates": ["product", "index"],
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "heading",
        "label": "Heading",
        "default": "Click here"
      },
      {
        "type": "color",
        "id": "text_color",
        "label": "Text Color for anchor tag",
        "default": "#000000"
      },
       {
        "type": "color",
        "id": "form_text_color",
        "label": "Text Color for Form Label",
        "default": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "type": "color",
        "id": "form_button_text_color",
        "label": "Text Color for Submit Button",
        "default": "#ffffff"
      },
      {
        "type": "color",
        "id": "form_button_background_color",
        "label": "Submit Button background color",
        "default": "#000000"
      },
       {
        "type": "checkbox",
       "id": "show_announcement",
       "label": "Show Form",
       "default": false
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your code so far? It is impossible for us to help without knowing what sort of frontend you use and such.

Comment: You understand that you're just slowing down your extension, making it fatter, and therefore being a real risk of having merchants just not use it due to bloat? If you cannot write fast vanilla JS for an extension, is jquery really your only choice? There are smaller, faster libraries these days to day much of what jQuery does.

Comment: I have create code according to jquery i can not change it. Please let me know how i can use jquery library with theme extensions in the APP

Comment: I have updated question can you please look at

Answer (score 0):

If your frontend is plain HTML, add

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

to the html file before JQuery is used.

Comment: OuterSoda 

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Lyfsize",
    "target": "section",
    "stylesheet": "front_shop.css",
    "javascript": "front_shop.js",
    "templates": ["product", "index"],

I need to how i can incude with  front_shop.js

Comment: Would you mind posting the whole code? It's hard to figure out what's going on with just that extract.

Comment: Please check in description

Comment: I have posted schema code

Comment: have updated question can you please look at